# Inverse Fourier Transform Of K-space Image...what is the object space scale?

Tags: optics, fourier-transform, diffraction

Checked around a buch and could not find any help. But I needed help with:

Understanding that if I get the Inverse FT of K-space data, what is the scaling on the X-space (object space) resultant image/data i.e. for every tick on the axis, how do I know the spatial length?

More detailed explanation in the below image.

[image]

Comment: Is this a [tag:homework] problem?

Comment: No, not at all. I am geniunely trying to understand this for a week now but cannot. I made the image in powerpoint because, at this point, I am desperate for help.

Comment: Did you read the link there to see how we define [tag:homework]? It's not "assigned in a class" type of question per se.

Comment: This is not for a class. Its for my overall understanding, but I guess I could tag as such. I'm not necessarily looking for some one to solve it, I dont think they can with the info I gave them...I just need to understand the scales.

Comment: One interesting point is that the inverse Fourier transform is, for all intents and purposes, the exact same as the forward Fourier transform. That's why few people use the term "inverse" in these contexts. The fact that "inverse" is being specified means the source for this statement probably isn't using the unitary version - i.e. they are using a version where one direction has a $2\pi$ in front and the other doesn't. Without more info, any answer could easily be off by a factor of $2\pi$ or so.

Comment: Even without that ambiguity, "K-space" is not a universally understood physics term. Or rather it is universal - it always means the Fourier transform of something "real." What that real thing is depends on context. What exactly is going on here? Is this a CCD on a camera? Are there optics involved? Is this an X-ray diffraction question? Without context this is unanswerable.

Comment: Thanks for the input! In a sense it can be treated as xray diffraction, but in actuality it is a transition radiation problem.Essentially what is happening is that a group of electrons are passing through a medium, each emitting their own photon/light wave. The emitted light travels some distance (far field) until it reaches a 200x200 pixel CCD. This is the Kspace image above; we know the angle and distance of the brightest band. When we find the IFFT of the image (literally using the Matlab function) assuming we know the phases, we get the object space image. The object space image...

Comment: ...SHOULD be the size of the group of electrons that emitted the light. The goal is to find the width of the object space image to see how big the electron group/bunch is. This is what I've been struggling with for a while now. Not a hw problem but a personal project I would like to understand completely!

Answer (score 2):

The *units* of your X-space are the inverse of the units of your K-space. So if your K-space is in $\mathrm{m}^{-1}$, then your X-space will be in $\mathrm{m}$.

To make the full circuit $f(x) \rightarrow F(k) \rightarrow f(x)$ requires an overall normalization factor of $1/2\pi$ to ensure that you get the function you started with. As Chris White points out in his [comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70392/inverse-fourier-transform-of-k-space-image-what-is-the-object-space-scale#comment144058_70392), there are a few different conventions on where exactly to put this normalization factor. Some put it entirely on one of the transformations. Some conventions split it between the two transforms, and put $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ on each integral; this has the advantage of making the Fourier transform and the inverse Fourier transform perfectly symmetrical with respect to $x$ and $k$.

In addition, some conventions for [wavenumber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavenumber) define it as cycles per unit distance (so that $xk = 1$), while some define wavenumber as radians per unit distance (so that $xk = 2\pi$).

Ultimately, you might need to multiply the axes in your X space by $1, \sqrt{2\pi},$ or $2\pi$, depending on the set of conventions your software is using, and the convention you have used to express your $k$ values. You should already know the latter. For the former, you will have to check the documentation for the Fourier transform in your software.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so firstly thanks so much for all of your help...

Secondly I have wrote down the solution (ATTACHED PDF) that one of the guys in my group gave me. But to be honest I don't understand the very first relation (in step one).

I specifically don't understand how the width of the peak in pixels fits in? Any guidance?

[image]

[image]

Comment: what software are you using for the plots and presentations?